# How to use Adobe fonts

Tags: fonts

I stumbled onto several folder named "Adobe" in TeXLive distribution, and it seemed like they are ready to be used. So, is there a way to use Adobe fonts in pdftex,like adobe symbol font for math and adobe times for text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you say

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

you'll be using Times and Symbol (plus some characters from other fonts).

However the standard set up uses URW clones of the fonts that are freely usable. If you don't want them, then use the following code:

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\pdfmapline{=ptmb8r Times-Bold 262178 " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc}
\pdfmapline{=ptmbi8r Times-BoldItalic 262242 " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc}
\pdfmapline{=ptmr8r Times-Roman 34 " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc}
\pdfmapline{=ptmri8r Times-Italic 98 " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc}
\pdfmapline{=psyr Symbol 4}
```

This will use the default Times and Symbol font coming with the PDF previewer or the printer. But, as Taco suggests, this may happen or not depending on arcane astral conjunctions.

Better to stick with the default setting and let pdflatex (partially) embed the fonts in the PDF file.

Comment: you should add an 'if you are lucky' to that last statement. These days, Adobe insists that you should include all fonts inside PDF documents, also previously predefined ones like Times-Roman. Failure to include all fonts may mean they end up being replaced by the multiple master fallback in Acroread, or producing errors/missing glyphs during printing.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the document of [`psnfss`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psnfss). There are several font packages that support Adobe PostScript fonts:

- `mathptmx`, Times and math and some others.
- `mathpazo`, Palatino and math and some others.
- `helvet`, Helvetica.
- `pifont`, Zapf Dingbats.

And `fourier`, `fouriernc` and so on, for other PostScript fonts. See also:
http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/