# Use standard PostScript fonts in Latex: Helvetica NOT NimbusSans

Tags: type1, helvetica

Let's start specifying my use case, as it might a bit a-typical. I want to offer on-demand generated drawings in PDF format from a website. (*) These PDF's are generated using the Python 'Pyx' package, which uses (La)Tex for generating PDF's.

As the result might by used by graphic designers, I want the document to be editable in Adobe Illustrator. I add small amounts of text to the graphics and the typesetting doesn't have to splendid. So, I would like the PDF to use one of the standard fonts: Helvetica, Times, Courier.

I manage to get a PDF with a font that looks like Times or Helvetica, but the moment I open it in Illustrator, the program tells me "The document uses fonts that are currently not available on your your computer". In the dialog, it shows me it has been using "CMSY10" and "NimbusSanL-Regu". Hence, my question:

***Is it possible to make LaTex use Helvetica or Times without embedding it in the document?***

Right now, I am trying to first get it right using a test.tex file and the xelatex command. If this works, then I can try to get it working it Pyx.

So far, what I tried is:

```
% Preamble
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}

% Packages
\usepackage{a4wide}

% Document
\begin{document}

It is only with the heart that one can see rightly; what is essential is invisible to the eye.

\end{document}
```

The result looks like Helvetica, but when I open it in Illustrator, I see:

[image: Screenshot from Adobe Illustrator showing the fonts used in the PDF]

Comment: you said you are using xelatex but your document is using pdflatex conventions \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} etc, which do you want to use? (pdflatex is probably easier since you want to use type 1 fonts I think)

Comment: you could try `\pdfmapline{=phvr8r Helvetica}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, the stupid but honest answer to your question would be: "Whatever PyX uses". I'm just gathering pieces of information. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that works! Thanks! If you'd be so kind to write your comment as an 'Answer', then I can mark it as "THE" answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Based on your suggestion, I've tried for the font family `Times`, with the code `\pdfmapline{=ptmr8r Times}
\pdfmapline{=ptmri8r Times-Italic}
\pdfmapline{=ptmbo8r Times-Bold}
\pdfmapline{=ptmbi8r Times-BoldItalic}` but this was not working, can you suggest what mistake I did? Please.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments by David Carliisle and Ulrike Fischer: To use the Helvetica font without embedding it into the document:

```
% Preamble
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\pdfmapline{=phvr8r Helvetica}
\usepackage{helvet}

% Packages
\usepackage{a4wide}

% Document
\begin{document}

It is only with the heart that one can see rightly; what is essential is invisible to the eye.

\end{document}
```

(Compared to my original approach, this means removing the line `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and adding the line `\pdfmapline{=phvr8r Helvetica}`.)

In addition, i used the command `pdflatex` instead of `xelatex` .

All these steps were necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer that [Ideogram found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/544712/238955), I had to change the line

```
\pdfmapline{=phvr8r Helvetica}
```

to

```
\pdfmapline{=phvr8r Helvetica 32 " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc}
```

maybe due to a newer version of pdflatex. I found this based on another [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21130).